# How do I align different sized divs without float

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the page, the divs below the horizontal menus need to be as following:

Div1 is the one with blue background

Div2 is the one red background (with elements with yellow background inside it)

Div3 is the one with  green background

I need div 1 to be top left, div 2 to be on the right, and div 3 to be on the bottom left, so they appear THIS WAY: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTHxZ.jpg

**HTML**

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
<div class="navigation">

    <div class="menu">
    <input type="button" value="Option 1" />
        <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="menu">
    <input type="button" value="Option 2" />
        <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
    <input type="button" value="Option 3" />
        <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        <a href="#">Link 9</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
    <input type="button" value="Option 4" />
        <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#">Link 10</a>
        <a href="#">Link 11</a>
        <a href="#">Link 12</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <input type="button" value="Option 5" />
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Link 13</a>
            <a href="#">Link 14</a>
            <a href="#">Link 15</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="topleft">
    Korisni linkovi:
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div class="contentright">
News
    <div class="news">
    <pre>Neki tekst za neke novine,
    detaljnije na linku ispod
    </pre>
    <a href="#">Detaljnije</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
    <pre>Neki tekst za neke novine,
    detaljnije na linku ispod
    </pre>
    <a href="#">Detaljnije</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
    <pre>Neki tekst za neke novine,
    detaljnije na linku ispod
    </pre>
    <a href="#">Detaljnije</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
    <pre>Neki tekst za neke novine,
    detaljnije na linku ispod
    </pre>
    <a href="#">Detaljnije</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
    <pre>Neki tekst za neke novine,
    detaljnije na linku ispod
    </pre>
    <a href="#">Detaljnije</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
    <pre>Neki tekst za neke novine,
    detaljnije na linku ispod
    </pre>
    <a href="#">Detaljnije</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottomleft">
<pre>
Bio jednom jedan zeka
Bio jednom jedan zeka
Bio jednom jedan zeka
Bio jednom jedan zeka
Bio jednom jedan zeka
Bio jednom jedan zeka
</pre>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    /*background-image:url("background.jpg");*/
}
.top
{
    margin-top:5%;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}
.top .left
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 40%;
}
.top .right
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    width: 40%;
}
.navigation
{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
}
.menu
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:15px;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.menu input
{
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu:first-child
{
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
}
.menu:last-child

{
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
}

.menu:hover

{
    border-color:gray;
}

.menu input:hover

{
    background-color:gray;
    color:black;
    border-color:gray;
}

.menu:hover .submenu
{
    display:block;
}

.submenu
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:gray;
    width:100%;
}
.submenu a
{
    display:block;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    padding-top:6px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
}
.submenu a:hover
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

.submenu a:first-child
{
    border-top:none;
}

.topleft
{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top:2%;
    box-shadow:2px 5px 10px black;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:verdana;
    background-color:blue;
}
.topleft ul
{
        display:inline;
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:inherit;
}
.topleft li
{
    padding:15px;
    margin:inherit;
}
.topleft li a
{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.topleft li a:hover
{
    background-color:gray;
}
.contentright
{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    margin-left:10%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.news
{
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.bottomleft
{
    background-color:green;
    display: block;
    margin-left:10%;
    box-shadow:2px 5px 10px black;
    width:155px;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/Le6y0wx8/

Please keep in mind that I'm not allowed to use float property.

Comment: have you tried placing both divs (1 and 3) in a container with fixed width? if there's not enough space horizontally elements will be displayed below. Or try playing with negative margins/absolute position.

Comment: I'm doing this for practice, and I'm later supposed to learn how to make these pages for different resolutions as well, is it good practice to use manually set width in that situation?

Comment: it all depends on what your page will display. If those 3 divs are all there is then define width as %. If div 1 and 3 are menus and should not change size as the window gets resized then set it in pixels and let div2 take up the remaining space. The best you can do now is try different possibilities , see how it goes and adapt to it.

Answer (score 0):

here is the [fiddle](https://codepen.io/mgkrish/pen/pdopYK?editors=0110) check it

if use flexbox design then there is not need for float

```
.container{
  display:flex;
}
```